# How can i tell google that i have removed the .html from my url?

Tags: html, url, seo, google-search

Hi I have recently removed the '.html' from the end of my url's to make them look more professional which was brilliant. However, now when I see my site on Google the old url which includes the '.html' still appears which produces people with an error page as expected. How can I tell Google that I have new url addresses so that people can visit my site again?

thanks!

Comment: Short answer: 1) there's nothing "unprofessional" about having an .html suffix on an HTML file - that's what you're *supposed* to do!.  2) The "trick" is to have an "index.html" in each directory (or generate content dynamically, e.g. Wordpress), then link to the directory path (instead of the .html file).  TO ANSWER YOUR QUESTION: You can't "update Google".  At best, you can add back your .html file to fix the link you broke.

Answer (score -2):

Best way to remove `.html extensions` is by adding it in `.htaccess` file. This way search engines will "understand" it, but you will not seeing the search result immediately, since search engine crawler, will take some time to update.

And make sure to submit your url in google. If you have **google webmaster** you will be able to see this process and status of your website more clearly.